# How to avoid fees when making purchases in a different country?

Tags: banking

I asked a similar question here about credit cards:

[How can I (a US citizen) set up my bank/money when I move to Portugal?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14356/how-can-i-a-us-citizen-set-up-my-bank-money-when-i-move-to-portugal)

From the answer there it seems like there are some cards that have no international transaction fees but there is always some sort of other fee(annual fees and hidden fees). I actually found a card that seems to have no fees:

https://www.revolut.com/us/

but I can't get it because I live in the US and it hasn't launched in the US yet.

Besides finding a no fees credit card, are there any other ways that I can avoid international transaction fees? What about PayPal? Obviously I could carry a bunch of cash on me but that's probably a little too risky.

Answer (score 3):

There are many US credit cards with no international transaction fees. You can use them while out of US and keep paying them from the US account.

See - https://www.creditkarma.com/credit-cards/no-foreign-fees